# How can a GKE persistent volume's provisioner be changed to use a CSI driver?

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, persistent-volumes, gce-persistent-disk, csi-driver

Our GKE PersistentVolumes were provisioned with kubernetes.io/gce-pd, but we want to take snapshots of our PVs using VolumeSnapshot. The documentation states that "[VolumeSnapshot](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volume-snapshots/#introduction) support is only available for CSI drivers." In order to use VolumeSnapshot we need to change existing PVs to use the pd.csi.storage.gke.io CSI driver.

What is the most efficient way to accomplish this change?

Comment: Additionally, is there a reason to NOT use csi? Because the default is often gce-pd  and then you cannot do snapshots. Is there any disadvantage of using csi if your cluster supports both?